# Using regex in the Find and Replace feature of RStudio to replace captured group with lower case

Tags: regex, rstudio

I'm trying to convert camelCase variable names into snake_case and want to use regex to do so. I thought a simple find `[a-z]([A-Z])` and replace with `_$L$1` would work, but it's actually putting "$L" into the variable name. What is the approach in RStudio (which uses the PERL engine for regex) to replace with the lowercase casing for a captured group?

Comment: Try `([a-z])([A-Z])` -> `$1_\l$2`.

Comment: Good catch on my prior regex removing the last letter of the first word, but `\l` doesn't work. It just replaces it with "\l". And for all of our sanity, I'll just explicitly state that I do have the regex box checked.

Comment: I do not think RStudio supports the case toggling operators. Look at the [documentation page](http://www.r-studio.com/Unformat_Help/index2.html?regularexpressions.html). Also: [*R Studio's implementation of regex is confusingly differentfrom R's default regex behavior.*](http://tagteam.harvard.edu/hub_feeds/1981/feed_items/573808)

Comment: More, PCRE does not support `\u` and `\l` operators: [*37  PCRE does not support `\L`, `\l`, `\N{name}`, `\U`, or `\u`*](http://www.pcre.org/pcre.txt).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[PCRE](http://www.pcre.org/pcre.txt) does not support `\u` and `\l` operators:

> *37  PCRE does not support `\L`, `\l`, `\N{name}`, `\U`, or `\u`*

RStudio does not support them either.

So, the best you can do with regex is switch on the `Regex` checkbox, and use 26 regexp replacements like:

```
([a-z])A -> $1a
([a-z])B -> $1b
 ....
([a-z])Z -> $1z
```

If possible, use Notepad++ or Sublime Text, or other [Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/format/perl_format.html)-powered tools that support `\u`/`\U...\E` and `\l`/`\L...\E` operators.

**Find What**: `([[:lower:]])([[:upper:]])` (or your `([a-z])([A-Z])`)
**Replace with**: `\1\l\2`

Comment: That is really unfortunate. :-(

Comment: The `\u`/`\U...\E` and `\l`/`\L...\E` operators can be used in Notepad++, Sublime Text and generally all Boost-powered tools. You can use `([[:lower:]])([[:upper:]])` -> `\1\l\2` there.

Comment: That actually might not be a bad way to go. Just copy and paste to Notepad++ or Vim and then copy it back to RStudio. Thanks for the suggestion!