# Number after captured group in regex

Tags: r, regex

I want to write a simple RegEx to add leading zeros to my R code. Simplest way is to find `(\s)\.(\d)` and replace it with `\10.\2`. But it doesn't work in R as it apparently thinks it's 10th captured group rather than 1st followed by a literal 0. According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34777503/using-regex-in-the-find-and-replace-feature-of-rstudio-to-replace-captured-group) question RStudio uses PCRE but no method for PCRE (or any other engine) from those described [here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html) works in RStudio find & replace feature. Is it possible to put a number after a captured group without leaving RStudio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a work-around, you can use lookarounds here:

**Search for**: `(?<=\s)\.(?=\d)`
**Replace with**: `0.`

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/daLTtt/1).